# C# Binding Data to Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding, web-controls

I am trying to bind a database row to a text box in C# so it is the default value (but the text box can still be edited).

The current issue i am having is that the text box will not let me attach a data source with the error (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox does not contain a definition for 'DataSource'....)

I am able to succesfully bind the datasource to a drop down list, but using the same code for a text box does not work.

```
        txtBox1.DataSource = "DataSource";
        txtBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just assign the value from the data source to the text box?  A textbox would only be able to represent 1 row / column of data anyway.  You could then apply the the value of the textbox back to the data source on save.  Without more context of what your trying to do / how you're doing it, it's hard to say for sure how to best accomplish this.

Comment: What exactly is "DataSource" , a datatable?

Comment: please add tag WebControls (or something) so people like me dont get their hopes up - that its about Winforms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that a `DataSource` contains multiple rows. A drop down can support that, as it will show one entry per row, but a TextBox doesn't support it. There is only one text field, which row from the data source should it use?

To set the text of a `TextBox` use the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a Value to the text box what you need to do is :

```
textBox1.Text= "MyText";
```

then the user can change that value and on the postback you use that value for whatever you need and the user

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind a DataSource to a TextBox in WebForms. You can set the text to a field in a DataRow using the indexer.

```
`txtBox1.Text = datarow["SomeField"]`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataView dv = DataSource.DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "id=1"; // or whatever as per your need to make sure only 1 row is there
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",dv,"id");
```